# Insert few line in Makefile.am if condition is true

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

I am trying to write a `Makefile.am`, where, if `Makefile.am` will be changed depending on `AC_CHECK_PROG` result of `configure.ac`.

As an example, in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CHECK_PROG([DEPF90_CHECK],[makedepf90],[yes],[no])
AM_CONDITIONAL([FOUND_MAKEDEPF90], [test "x$DEPF90_CHECK" = xyes])
AM_COND_IF([FOUND_MAKEDEPF90],[a depend rule in makefile.am],[Some other thing in Makefile.am])
```

So, when `makedepf90` exists, I want a depend rule in Makefile[.am].
The depend rule in `makefile.am` looks like:

```
depend depend.mk:
    makedepf90 $(vimtst_SOURCES) >depend.mk
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `AM_COND_IF`. The `AM_CONDITIONAL` rule will enable you to write this in your `Makefile.am`:

```
if FOUND_MAKEDEPF90
depend depend.mk:
    makedepf90 $(vimtst_SOURCES) >depend.mk
endif
```